# Jar to Mac OSX App Bundle with app bundler

Tags: java, macos, bundle

I'm trying to bundle my .jar to a MacOSX app bundle, using `app bundler`.
[I'm following this tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)

It says to add a `lib` folder to the high-level project directory, but I don't know what that means. I've been looking everywhere for it, and I cannot find out what it is. That's my only problem I have, anyone know?

EDIT:

Here is my `build.xml` file:

```
<project name="Rage Mage" basedir=".">
<taskdef name="ragemage"
         classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
         classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

<target name="bundle-RageMage">
    <delete dir="appBundle" failonerror="false"/>
    <mkdir dir="appBundle"/>
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="bundle"
        name="Rage Mage"
        displayname="Rage Mage"
        icon="res/icon.icns"
        identifier="ragemage.src.Window"
        mainclassname="ragemage.src.Window">
        <classpath file="dist/ragemage_1.1.1.jar" />
    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine that the,in directory are any and all of your dependent jars/libraries. The tutorial is based on using NetBeans, which stores it's main jar in the dist directory and all the dependent jars in the dist/lib directory

Comment: @MadProgrammer Didn't see it was for NetBeans. Do you know of any alternatives for Eclipse?

Comment: Basically it's the same process, you need to copy all the relevant Jars to the "high-level project", in what ever structure that Eclipse makes them in...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've been looking for how to make a MacOSX app bundle for a looooong time now, and this app bundler tool still doesn't work for me. I've tried so many things, and I have no idea how to do it. Do you know an easy way to do it, that you have used before?

Comment: I thought the tutorial was reasonably straight forward, haven't really tried it my self, have tried reading through the [AppBundler Task Doc](https://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so, after having a little play around, this is what I understand...

- Download [Java Application Bundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler) and place it in the `lib` directory of your project.  You will need to create this directory...
- Create a new Ant script into your project directory, call it what ever you like...Also, take the time to read through the [`AppBundler` Task Docs](https://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html)

The ant script should be based on the following skeleton...

```
<project name="ButtonDemo" default="bundle-buttonDemo" basedir=".">        
    <taskdef name="bundleapp"
             classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
             classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />
    <!-- See the lib reference here, this is why you need to use the lib directory! -->

    <target name="bundle-buttonDemo">
        <delete dir="appBundle" failonerror="false"/>
        <mkdir dir="appBundle"/>
        <bundleapp outputdirectory="appBundle"
            name="ButtonDemo"
            displayname="Button Demo"
            identifier="components.ButtonDemo"
            mainclassname="components.ButtonDemo">
            <!-- The following is important and should point to your build -->
            <classpath file="dist/ButtonDemo.jar" />
            <!-- You can have multiple instance of classpath if you 3rd party or
                 dependent jars in different locations -->
        </bundleapp>
    </target>
</project>
```

- Build your project
- Run the ant script, using (something like) `ant -f {You App Bundler script}`

The app bundle, in this case `ButtonDemo.app` will be created in `appBundle` directory.  If you can, browse the contents of the `ButtonDemo.app/Contents/Java` and make sure all your required Jar files are there...

Happy bundling!

**Updated based on updated build.xml file**

1- There is no `default` target specified by the `project` tag.  Think of this like your "main class" or "main" method, without, ant has no idea what you want to run...

```
<project name="Rage Mage" basedir="." default="bundle-RageMage">
```

2- The `name` of the `taskdef` is significant and you use it in the any script to identify what ant should do when it hits your tag reference...

So based on your example, you either need to change the name of the `taskdef` from `ragemage` to `bundleapp` or change the `bundleapp` tag to `ragemage`...

Either change this...

```
<taskdef name="bundleapp"
     classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
     classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />
```

or this (in target `bundle-RageMage`)

```
<ragemage outputdirectory="bundle"
    name="Rage Mage"
    displayname="Rage Mage"
    icon="res/icon.icns"
    identifier="ragemage.src.Window"
    mainclassname="ragemage.src.Window">
    <classpath file="dist/ragemage_1.1.1.jar" />
</ragemage>
```

Personally, I'd leave it as `bundleapp`, but that's me...

3- The `delete`, `mkdir` and `outputdirectory` attribute of `bundleapp` are related...

```
<delete dir="appBundle" failonerror="false"/>
<mkdir dir="appBundle"/>
<bundleapp outputdirectory="bundle"...
```

Either, make them all `appBundle` or `bundle`, what every you want...

4- You main class is unlikely to be `ragemage.src.Window` and is probably going to be `Window`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60059/discussion-on-answer-by-madprogrammer-jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler).

Comment: The link to download Java Application Bundler is not working!

Comment: @AyushyaChitransh Well, [there's one alternative](https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler/)

Comment: @JAnton A quick bit of googling - [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html), if you want to get your hands dirty [Bundle the Java JRE into your macOS application](http://www.balthisar.com/blog/bundle-the-jre/).  There's also [Self-Contained Application Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) and maybe [Converting a .jar into a Mac OS X app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718953/converting-a-jar-into-a-mac-os-x-app)

Comment: @JAnton Since this question was answered in 2014, I personally would consider it out-of-date.  During my quick google, I also noticed [Jorl17/jar2app](https://github.com/Jorl17/jar2app) which might be worth a look over