# How to Create a Mac OS X Application Bundle for Java with Windows?

Tags: java, macos, deployment

I am trying to create a Mac OS X Application Bundle (.app file) for a Java application using Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 on Windows 8.1.

I have read a number of online posts indicating that there is an Export > Mac OS X Application Bundle feature in Eclipse. However, I cannot locate this feature.

I have been trying various methods over the past two days to try to accomplish this and nothing seems to work--ANT build files etc. (I cannot figure out where to put the appbundler JAR).

Is Eclipse Export Mac OS X Application Bundle still part of Eclipse 4.0 (and where?)?

Comment: On the Mac version of Eclipse Luna, It's under File→Export→Other

Comment: You could try using the [Java Application Bundler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html), demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978212/jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler/24992828#24992828)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using both AppBundler and JarBundler. I place the AppBundler JAR in a newly created directory in the main project called lib. As for the past few days, when I modify the build.xml file, I keep getting taskdef class com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]. This happens no matter where I place AppBuilder (I even had placed in the the native ANT directory yesterday with no success.)