# Compiling my Java program to intall on Mac

Tags: java, macos, installation

I've written my program. It works as I want it to. I want to distribute it to Windows, Linux, and Mac users, not as a JAR file, but as a program they can install and use natively. I was able to do this for Windows and Linux thanks to the excellent program, Excelsior Jet!

Can anybody tell me the best way to do this for Mac?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) and [Java Application Bundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler).  This will allow you to package your application as a Mac .app bundle.

Then you could look at something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978212/jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler/24992828#24992828) as an example

There are plenty of cross platform installers, I tend to use a [izPack](http://izpack.org/) because it's free and has Ant integration.

Answer (score 0):

This program can create executables for Linux, Windows, and Mac OSX.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/