# Creating an explicit working directory with Java Application Bundler

Tags: java, macos

I love Java Application Bundler https://java.net/projects/appbundler

The one thing I have not figured out is how to explicitly set the workspace. By default it makes Users/<user-home> the working directory.  Is there any way to set that to be in the /Contents directory in the bundle? If not, is there a way to make AppBuldler copy folders and files to the user's home directory?

I got some great advice from @MadProgrammer on how to use Java Application Bundler [Compiling my Java program to intall on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520758/compiling-my-java-program-to-intall-on-mac)

And I feel like I got close to an answer here:

http://grokbase.com/t/openjdk/macosx-port-dev/122w8hw0nh/appbundler-wrong-working-directory

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From what I understand and have read, "Application Builder" itself doesn't set the working context, it's actually the underlying native API (MacOS) which is doing it.  What I've ended up doing is either placing configuration/resources within the application context (class-path) and using `Class#getResource` or using `{user.home}/Library/{application-name}` as for storing application specific information, which seems to the preferred location

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer - these sound like they could work for me. My program looks for a series of directories: app/xsl, app/in, app/out, app/temp, in the workspace. Any chance you could provide a small sample of each method, and for the second time in as many posts, save the day for me?

Comment: I am trying the second method from @MadProgrammer - seems nearly there. My application installs at '/Applications/XMarker.app'. I've set the program to look for XSLs in '/Applications/XMarker.app/Contents/Resources/xmarker-files/xsl' and to read/write files at '/Applications/XMarker.app/Contents/Resources/xmarker-files/temp'. It is definitely reading (I have a button to report that). But it does not seem to be able to write. Any ideas? Please?