# Netbeans Platform installer mac OS X with bundle jre ( private Jvm on Mac)

Tags: java, jvm, netbeans-platform

i work on Netbeans platform application with jdk 1.8u40. 
 i want to package installer for Mac OS X with private jvm bundle jre jdk               1.8u40. i create an installer for linux & windows with bundle Jre, but Mac os x i cannot. i don't know how to use jarbundler with netbeans platform to create installer for Mac Os X. 
Is there another to bundle jre for mac application?
thanks

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978212/jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler/24992828#24992828)

Comment: what i mean how to create installer for mac with private jvm from netbeans platform application (RCP) . Is there way to use jarbundler with netbeans platform application (RCP)? i don't know how to use it.

Comment: i install jarbundler but it is not work on my mac, can you help me, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a omission which dates back when the NetBeans Installer project ([NBI](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBI)) was made some time ago.

There's an [RFE](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=250103) open for this and most of this text is from that RFE.

The fact is NBI currently (as of NB 8.0.2) doesn't support a bundled JRE with Mac OS X.

Why this is so, I don't know, but I'm assuming the reason is that at the time NBI was created the concept of a bundled JRE on Mac OS X was somewhat alien. At that time Mac OS X *always* came with a pre-installed JRE. Today Mac OS X comes without a JRE pre-installed and Apple actively encourages developers to bundle a private JRE with the application. In fact if you want your application in the Mac App Store then you MUST bundle a private JRE with your application.

There are basically two ways to fix the problem:

1. You can wait for the RFE to be accepted and fixed.
2. Just do the fix yourself.

Below, I'll focus on the second approach. It involves checking out NB core source code and building your own `nbi-engine.jar` file and then using that in your project rather than the one that comes with the platform itself.

1. Start by checking out the latest NB source code from Mercurial.
   Something like `hg clone http://hg.netbeans.org/main-golden/` should
   get you going.
2. Use your IDE (NetBeans!) to open the project located at `nbi/engine`
   in the files you've just checked out from Mercurial. Once opened it will look something like this: [image: NBI Engine project]
3. Within that project locate the source code file: 
   `org/netbeans/installer/wizard/components/actions/CreateMacOSAppLauncherAction.java`.
4. To this file you simply have to add the same code as exist in the equivalent `CreateNativeLauncherAction.java` file in same directory. You can find the exact changes that needs to be made to `CreateMacOSAppLauncherAction.java` in the [patch file attached to the RFE](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=151735&action=diff).
5. Now re-build the "NBI Engine" project. As a result a new `nbi-engine.jar` is produced. You'll need to salvage the `nbi-engine.jar` file from that project and put it somewhere else. After that you'll no longer need the "NBI Engine" project and you can delete it. In fact you can delete everything you've checked out from Mercurial in step 1.

That's it.

What is left now is to figure out how to get your project to use the newly generated `nbi-engine.jar` file as opposed to the one that comes with the NB Platform. In the following I'll explain how to do that for a Maven-based NB Platform project. If your project is Ant based then you're on your own. :-(

In your POM file make the following adjustment:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <userSettings>
            <!-- This will override parameter of the same name set by the MOJO -->
            <nbi.engine.jar>path-to-an-alternative-nbiengine-jar</nbi.engine.jar>
        </userSettings>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That's all.

Your next issue will be how to create JRE bundle for Mac out of the official JRE packages from Oracle. But that's not the question you asked. :-)