# On a Mac, how do I create icon that will take a .jar file, open a terminal, and run that .jar file?

Tags: java, jar, terminal

Long story short, I have created a text-based-game, and I want to make it easily transferable to friends' computers.

I don't want to have to give instructions on how to open a terminal and run the file. Can you provide step-by-step instructions on how to (at the minimum) be able to double click the `DustToDiamonds.jar` file to have it run in the terminal or to (ideally) be able to create an actual icon to be pressed which causes a terminal to open and run the game?

As of now, when I double click on the .jar file I get a popup window with the following error: `"The Java JAR file "DustToDiamonds.jar" could not be launched`. Check the Console for possible error messages."

I used eclipse to create a .jar for me, and when I run `jar -jar DustToDiamonds.jar` in the terminal it runs. I don't know anything about Application Bundling or shell commands, so if those are necessary I would need actual code to work off of. I am using a Mac running El Capitan.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might need to create a app bundle, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978212/jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler/24992828#24992828) for example.  You might also be able to create a shell script which runs the jar in a terminal automatically, but I've not tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use some 3rd-party solution to bundle your application into an executable. For example, you can try a [packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr).

Earlier, it was passible to use a JarBundler, but it is not provided with newest version of MacOS. If you, possibly, use a Gradle as build tool, you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/crotwell/gradle-macappbundle) to create executable .app. There is like the same solution for the [Ant scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) and I suppose you can find something for Maven, if you need it.

As an alternative, you can create a shell script, like for any unix-system, and make it executable. You van find an example [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/65136).

Comment: I tried the link you provided and it gave me this error in the terminal: "/Users/MyName/Desktop/executable_app ; exit;
/Users/MyName/Desktop/executable_app: line 1: !/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory"

Comment: Which one? There is a number of different solutions. Furthermore, if some of them doesn't work, you have to provide an info about how you tried to use it or may be read a little bot more about it in user manual.

Comment: For the shell script. I double clicked the "executable_app" and my terminal window opened then gave me that error. "/Users/MyName/Desktop/executable_app ; exit; /Users/MyName/Desktop/executable_app: line 1: !/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory"

Comment: Where is /usr/bin/env from? Example doesn't use it, but /bin/sh

Comment: "/Users/MyName/Desktop/executable_app ; exit;
/Users/MyName/Desktop/executable_app: line 1: !/bin/sh: No such file or directory"

Comment: I was messing around with it. But I got the same message with !/bin/sh as well

Comment: @ParkerAllen strange... Don't you forget a #? I was tried this solution  locally and it works for me.

Comment: I did forget a #. Now I get this message in the terminal: "/Users/Parker/Desktop/executable_app ; exit;
ParkerAllensMBP:~ Parker$ /Users/Parker/Desktop/executable_app ; exit;". The game still does not run

Comment: If you are building your jar using maven, I have written a maven build plugin that wraps the packr java api. The plugin is built around version 2 of packr. This way when you build your jar, you will also get an executable (.app, exe, or linux depending on your config).

https://github.com/stevenmz/packer-maven-plugin