# Create an OS X Executable from a Windows Machine?

Tags: java, macos

Okay so I made a small java game and packaged it into an .exe and it works just fine... for Windows users. My friends with Unix based systems can't launch the executable so I'm wondering how can I package my game for all operating systems? Is there some sort of bundler I can use?

Comment: Essentially you need to package it as a `.app` (which is just a fancy pancy directory), you can do this from windows (mostly), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978212/jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler/24992828#24992828), in recent years, Apple has required the JRE to be bundled with it, you'll only get that to work if you have a Mac and the JRE you're targeting installed

Comment: @MadProgrammer
So there's no way to package it as `.app` using a Windows computer?

Comment: As I said, you can do it, but you will need to rely on the end user having Java installed, which Apple is discouraging and would prefer the JRE was bundled with it. So depending on the problems you want to have will depend on which method you use (bundled or unbundled)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ohh, sorry for my misunderstanding. What method would I use if I know the end user already has Java installed (unbundled JRE).

Comment: Assuming they are using at lest the same version of Java, then you should be able to create a "unbundled" package, which should be one of examples in the linked example

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh okay I see now. Thank you very much!