# Converting a .jar into a Mac OS X app

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, software-distribution

I'm trying to create a java-based GUI for both Mac and windows. So far, I've been able to create an executable `.jar` file that runs on Windows.

The issue I'm running into is running that `.jar` on Mac. When I double-click to run, it says I should use `-XstartOnFirstThread` option to run the `.jar`. So, I've created a shell script that simply opens it with the following line of code:

```
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar myJar.jar
```

This runs the program well, but it's not a solution that is easily distributable. So, I'm trying to bundle the .jar into a Mac app. So far, everything I've tried results in the same error code:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application MyApp.app with error -10810
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- JarBundler (link [here](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/)): same issue
- Java Tutorial: 
  tried following this tutorial, but appbundler seems not to exist anymore (at least I can't find it on my mac and I can't find it on Java's website) and most of the links to other softwares that are on this page are dead.
- AppBundler ant task (link [here](https://github.com/joshmarinacci/AppBundler)): Couldn't quite firgure out how to use this.
- Eclipse OS-X App Bundler: same issue.
- changing permissions on the executable JavaApplicationStub within the app: same issue
- bundling the app on my own from scratch: same issue.

I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point, is there anything I am missing?

EDIT: The .jar file that I'm using was created by Eclipse's "create runnable JAR file" export option. Not sure if this makes a different or not.

Comment: I believe the Java stub executable used by JarBundler, AppBundler, etc. has been deprecated for some time, at least since OS X 10.8. If you want to have an `.app` bundle with Java code on MacOS now, I think you need to build your own JavaApplicationStub-like program and run your code through JNI.

Comment: @wmorrell I've never used JNI before-what exactly would I need to do? Do you know of any resources/tutorials I can use to do this?

Comment: @Agastya Sharma can you provide your jar, if its possible to share it openly.

Comment: @JTeam just wondering why you'd need the jar-I'd like to limit its exposure before it's been deployed

Comment: @AgastyaSharma i was looking for that jar, so that i can test my answer with your jar. Anyways I tested that with Mario.jar, it is working, pls check my answer.

Comment: @JTeam I tried with Mario.jar and it worked but it didn't with my .jar file-if it's not too much trouble would you be able to look at my jar file?

Comment: @AgastyaSharma how can you provide me your jar.. Email?

Answer (score 8):

I just tested this with this [Mario.jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/super-mario-bros-java/?source=typ_redirect)

**Steps:**

1. Make sure python is installed on your mac, if not use [brew](https://brew.sh/) and fire brew install python3
2. git clone https://github.com/Jorl17/jar2app
3. cd jar2app
4. sudo ./install.sh /usr/local
5. /usr/local/jar2app ~/Downloads/Mario.jar // replace jar path with your jar
6. check new .app is created in the current directoty

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I used to convert a .jar (ShowTime.jar, Class ShowTime) into an .app, On MacOS Terminal:

```
mkdir -p package/macosx
cp ShowTime.icns package/macosx
jdk=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
$jdk/bin/javapackager -version
$jdk/bin/javapackager -deploy -native dmg \
   -srcfiles ShowTime.jar -appclass ShowTime -name ShowTime \
   -outdir deploy -outfile ShowTime -v
cp deploy/bundles/ShowTime-1.0.dmg show-time-installer.dmg
ls -l
```

This is from where I take the example: [How to Create a Mac OS X Installer
for a Java Application](http://centerkey.com/mac/java/)

Comment: I tried using this and when I tried to open the app that the javapackager made with my .jar file, it gave me the same -10810 error code. I ran through the tutorial and it worked, so I'm not sure what my issue is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually AppBundler is what you are looking for, but you've said: "Couldn't quite figure out how to use this". So, here you are how it is used:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html
.
But pls care much of the links in this documentation are changed or removed, yet it explains how AppBudler works.

Comment: I think you and I may be talking about different app bundlers in this case. I've tried AppBundler (a GitHub project) and appbundler (released by Java). neither has worked for me.