# Integrating Java Class File with Java Virtual Machine to Create APP File for macOS Systems

Tags: java, macos, jvm

I have a standalone and only Java Class File.
I would like to package the class file to .app application file for macOS systems.
Also, I would like to integrate Java VM for macOS in the packaged app file to run on systems without JVM installed on.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: please share what you tried so far.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978212/jar-to-mac-osx-app-bundle-with-app-bundler